# POST Row Id to a new page for editing

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help me out here I have about 1 day experience of C# ASP.NET web dev and I am stuck on something really simple. I am much more experienced in PHP and jQuery.

What I need to do:

- Create a GridView and display data from MSSQL DB `[done]`
- Add buttons to each row to enable direct editing of values in two columns `[done]`
- Each row represents a list of equipment that the user can edit/save, and I need to add an extra "Edit Details" button to each row `[done]`
- Upon clicking the "Edit Details" button, I need to pass the id of that list to a new page where user can edit and save the list

I have added a `HyperLinkField` for the row id to be passed on, in Visual Studio I have tried to config it so that the value can be read on the receiving page with `Request.Params["xxxx"]` but it is not working.

In PHP I would just create a `POST <form>` with hidden `<input>` values and obtain the value by `$_POST["xxxx"]`

However it seems that all this fancy ASP.NET and Visual Studio DataSource pointer/reference and config things are making things more complicated than I wished.

I greatly appreciate any help given, or any resources that will be helpful for me to transfer my skills in PHP over to ASP.NET with C#.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Ok will remember that next time, thanks John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing it through query string use

```
string value = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();;
```

If you are passing it through post use

```
string value = Request.Forms["id"].ToString();
```